# Object is not an object instance en DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn

I'm trying to bring a list of SQL and it will be load into a datagridview. After that, some fields must be DataGridViewComboBoxColumn type, so the user can select any options from the combobox columns. This is the code I have done:

```
public async void ConfigurarGrilla()
    {
        try
        {
            var responseArea = await servicio.AreaGetAllAsync();
            var responseEmpresa = await servicio.EmpresaGetAllAsync();

            if (responseArea.IsValid && responseEmpresa.IsValid)
            {
                listaArea = responseArea.Value;
                listaEmpresa = responseEmpresa.Value;

                dgvArticulos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dtColumn = dgvArticulos.Columns["CodArea"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
                dtColumn.DataSource = listaArea;
                dtColumn.DisplayMember = "CodArea";

                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dtColumn2 = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvArticulos.Columns["RazonSocial"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
                dtColumn2.DataSource = listaEmpresa;
                dtColumn2.DisplayMember = "RazonSocial";

                LoadDocumento();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(responseArea.ErrorMensaje);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error " + ex.Message, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

The responseArea.Value and responseEmpresa.Value methods bring the list from the BD, they contain information when I debug, but in line dtColumn.DataSource = listaArea is where I get the error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I don't know what is the problem. All my objects have been  initialized

Comment: *1)* *object is not an object instance*?! I've not seen this error message ever. Is it the real message or you replaced somethings or you shortened it? *2)* Make sure `dtColumn` is not null. Maybe the column which you defined is not of type `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` *3)* Also it seems you've forgot to set `ValueMember` and `DataPropertyName` for your columns.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I modified the message.

Comment: OK, so you read the part *1* in first comment. If you read other parts too probably your problem will be solved.

Comment: Well.. The mistake was the column type in my datagridview!!! Thanks!